# Create Aggregate Result With Over Partition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that need to calculate some values.

```
id  branch  coa mtu slid    db      cr   date        SumBySLID
1   0001    XYZ IDR 123     1000    300  2016-01-01  800
2   0001    XYZ IDR 123     400     500  2017-03-01  800
3   0001    XYZ IDR 123     700     500  2011-03-01  800
4   0001    XYZ IDR 1111    400     500  2017-03-01  6400
5   0001    XYZ IDR 1111    7000    500  2017-03-01  6400
```

The Column SUMbySLID is generate by SUM(db-cd) and grouping by branch,coa,mtu,slid. Actually I can get SUMbySLID  values by GROUP By Query. I tried to use OVER PARTION BY function so I can show all data with column SUMbySLID. But when I added a filter date='2017/01/01', data with ID=2 show SumBySLID is -100.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [id]
      ,[branch]
      ,[coa]
      ,[mtu]
      ,[slid]
      ,[db]
      ,[cr]
      ,date
      ,SUM(db-cr) OVER(PARTITION BY branch,coa,mtu,slid)
  FROM [Testing].[dbo].[Tbl_Test_COA]
WHERE date='2017-03-01'
```

I want the id number 2 to still show SumBySLID =800 even after some filter with WHERE clause. How to solve it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery before filtering:

```
SELECT tc.*
FROM (SELECT tc.*,
             SUM(db-cr) OVER (PARTITION BY branch, coa, mtu, slid)
      FROM [Testing].[dbo].[Tbl_Test_COA] tc
     ) tc
WHERE date = '2017-03-01'
```